# Mingw error starting process. cannot run program c:\users\desktop\file\c: launching failed

Tags: c, eclipse

I just installed eclipse to program in C, I can't run any program, it gives me the following error:

Error starting process.
Cannot run program "C: \ Users \ Francesco \ Desktop \ File \ FrancescoLomazzo \ Esercitazione_2_21_Ottobre.c": Launching failed

Error in final launch sequence.

While if I try to debug a program it gives me the following error:

Failed to execute MI command:
-file-exec-and-symbols C:/Users/Francesco/Desktop/File/FrancescoLomazzo/Esercitazione_2_21_Ottobre.c

How do I solve this problem? Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you have a C compiler already installed and configured in Eclipse?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to run the source file as an executable. You have to compile it first.